# Edit external CSS with html/javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, external

How do I change a value of something placed in an external CSS file? So basically all my pages are linked to a css file (which has the background to all the pages) I'm trying to change the value of the background via a click of a button.. This is my code:

html:

```
<button style="background:url(images/bg.png);" onclick="main()"><font color="#FFFFFF">Image</button>
<button style="background-color:#000;" onclick="main()"><font color="#FFFFFF">Black</button>
<button style="background-color:#030;" onclick="main()"><font color="#FFFFFF">Green</button>
<button style="background-color:#006;" onclick="main()"><font color="#FFFFFF">Blue</button>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    background:url(images/bg.png);
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function main(clicked){
        //Doesnt work
        document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.background="#00FF00";
    }
</script>
```

How can I change the background in the css by clicking the button?

Comment: Why don't you apply your `css/css class` on the element ? You are not passing any argument while invoking `main()` but you are accepting one..

Comment: How can I change the background?Fire this `document.body.style.background="#FF0000"`

Comment: @Rayon Oops I edited the code before posting it here, the buttons had an ID and the button id were being passed as an argument. Its not needed tho..

Comment: Try `function main(elem){ elem.style.background="#00FF00";
    }` and `onclick="main(this)"` or if you want to apply `css` for `body`, refer comment posted by @SatejS..

Comment: @Satej That will just change the background of the current page, I want to edit the .css file so the entire website background can change.

Comment: @user3926730, How about using `sessionStorage/localStorage/cookie` for that ? Change applied by `JS` will be lost once the page is reloaded right ?

Comment: Problem you're going to face is, if you go to another page, it's not going to stay the updated color.You could try some way of writing to the file i'm guessing, or what @RayonDabre suggests.

Comment: @rayon, I never thought of that, thanks for the idea, I'm gonna try it out..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<button>Click me</button>

button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
button[0].onclick = function() {
  document.body.style.background = "#00FF00";
}
```

[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/55L0xhg4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to change the background style in the CSS file itself.

You can't change a CSS file stored on a server using Javascript. You will need to invoke a server function to do this. Are you using any server technology (such as PHP or ASP.Net)? If so, make the button click call a function on the server to make the change in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS in **Three** ways.

1. By adding a `.css` file and
2. By having a `<style>` tag.
3. Lastly with `style` attribute in an element;

When we manipulate appearances of an element with JavaScript, we usually change properties inside the `style` attribute. But we also can change things inside `<style>` tag, but I will not recommend that. But we can never change something in a `.css` file. Even the changes in the `<style>` tag or `style` attributes happens only in DOM.

So there is no way to change External Css with JavaScript. But you sure can change CSS inside `style` attribute. Run the code below. Open Chrome Inspector and select `<body>` tag. Then click on the button and see what happens.

```js
document.getElementById('changeBg').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.style = "background:red;"
})
```

```css
body {
  background: blue;
}

button{
  margin:100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="changeBg">Click here to change Background</button>
</body>
```